# Navigating between different pages in an ios app

Tags: ios

I'm practicing making apps on **`xcode6`** with swift.

How can I make the navigation between the pages work in such a manner that the new page comes in from the right and if I want to go back to a previous page, it comes in through the left.

I tried using show and show-detail segues but for both of them the next/previous page comes in from the bottom.

Comment: write here code you are using ?

Comment: I haven't written any code, just used the storyboard and linked the pages using segues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed your viewController in `UINavigationController`. Select your controller in storyboard and in Menu `Editor->Embed in->Navigation Controller`. Now use `Show` segue

Comment: Thanks mate! The new page comes in from the right now, however, the previous page also comes in from the right only...

Comment: I think you created segues for the both View controller which they push to each other. Your segues should be one way.